# Sum Total datagridview 1 colums (HH:mm) VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

hello all please help me ..
I have a datagridview that his data came from an excel file that I uploaded ..
the problem lies in a total hour (work hour - HH:mm) this is my code

```
 Private Sub Hitung()
    Dim jamkerja As Short
    jamkerja = 0
    For t As Integer = 0 To DGVexcel.Rows.Count - 1
        jamkerja = jamkerja + Val(DGVexcel.Rows(t).Cells(7).Value)
    Next
    txtjamkerja.Text = jamkerja
End Sub
```

please help me to get the total value of hour and minute into a TEXTBOX
see this picture : [image]

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way would be to loop through each item while adding the value to a timespan object.  (See: http://www.dotnetperls.com/timespan)

```
Private Sub Hitung()
    Dim jamkerja As Short
    Dim timespan As new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    jamkerja = 0
    For t As Integer = 0 To DGVexcel.Rows.Count - 1
        'jamkerja = jamkerja + Val(DGVexcel.Rows(t).Cells(7).Value)

        Dim value = Val(DGVexcel.Rows(t).Cells(7).Value)         

        Dim interval As TimeSpan
        If Not TimeSpan.TryParse(value, interval)

           timespan.Add(interval)
        End If
    Next
    txtjamkerja.Text = timespan.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: James Shaw thanks for the reply but why the result in his becoming 00:00:00 textbox, I just took hours and minutes (HH: mm), do you have another solution to get the total hours worked in a datagridview and pops in the textbox (example : total hour= 130 hour)? sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: Debug your code. Step through and determine that Value is being populated. You can also initialize as the following: Dim timespan As New TimesSpan(0,0,0,0) 'Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds